# COSMOS - Operating System Development - Error Setup Did Not Start?

Tags: c#, operating-system, cosmos

As a result of starting to use c# more often, I decided to start using the COSMOS development kit. A link to the project can be found [here](http://cosmos.codeplex.com).

However, I have read a tutorial of how to use COSMOS with vs 2013. Everything was going well until the installer gave me the following error:
[image: An image showing the error]

Nothing like COSMOS and other self-setup dev kits EVER work for me even though I follow the exact instructions set out by the developers!

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

EDIT: I am on Windows 7 SP1, I use Visual Studio 2013 (if vs 2013 wasn't clear enough) and I have all the required prerequisites functioning correctly (if 'I follow the exact instructions set by the developer' wasn't clear enough). I have a 64-bit version of both Windows and Visual Studio, as surprising as this may seem, running on a 64-bit machine. Please do not down vote this question because of lack of information - The picture and this paragraph is all the information and data I have about my environment and development with COSMOS.

Comment: Copy the error using the copy button and see if anything useful shows up?

Comment: It just copies the error shown - Setup did not start... @Bobson

Comment: Provide more information on your environment.  What version of Visual Studio are you using? What OS are you running it on?  Do you have all the prerequisites listed [here](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20Dev%20Kit&referringTitle=Home) installed and working?

Comment: @Bobson in case my original question wasn't clear enough (which I am sure it was - you must have read incorrectly of badly), I stated both what version of visual studio I am using and that I follow the EXACT instructions left by developers - implying the idea that I have followed all of the tutorials, including prerequisite software.

Comment: Also the picture shows that prerequisite software had passed the setup test successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code for COSMOS [here](https://github.com/tgiphil/Cosmos/blob/master/source2/Build/Cosmos.Build.Builder/CosmosTask.cs), this is the code that's currently running:

```
// This is a hack to avoid the UAC dialog on every run which can be very disturbing if you run
// the dev kit a lot.
Start(@"schtasks.exe", @"/run /tn " + Quoted("CosmosSetup"), true, false);

// Must check for start before stop, else on slow machines we exit quickly because Exit is found before
// it starts.
// Some slow user PCs take around 5 seconds to start up the task...
int xSeconds = 10;
var xTimed = DateTime.Now;
Echo("Waiting " + xSeconds + " seconds for Setup to start.");
if (WaitForStart("CosmosUserKit-" + mReleaseNo, xSeconds * 1000))
{
    throw new Exception("Setup did not start.");
}
Echo("Setup is running. " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(xTimed).ToString(@"ss\.fff"));

// Scheduler starts it an exits, but we need to wait for the setup itself to exit before proceding
Echo("Waiting for Setup to complete.");
WaitForExit("CosmosUserKit-" + mReleaseNo);
```

The key line (and comments) are:

```
// This is a hack to avoid the UAC dialog on every run which can be very disturbing if you run
// the dev kit a lot.
Start(@"schtasks.exe", @"/run /tn " + Quoted("CosmosSetup"), true, false);
```

For some reason, that program didn't start within the 10 seconds allocated to it, so it bombed out.  Given the comment associated, I suspect that the "hack" failed on your machine.

`schtasks.exe` is the [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The `/run` and `/tn` flags tell it to immediately run the task named as `Quoted("CosmosSetup")`.  I don't know what that value is, but my guess is that `schtasks.exe` is failing for you because you aren't an administrator.

Check the event log on your system for any related errors.